# JavaScript "match" doesnt match

Tags: javascript, regex

My code looks like follows

```
var html = $(el).html().toString();
html = '2012-05-10';
var re = new RegExp('^(19|20)\d\d[- /.](0[1-9]|1[012])[- /.](0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])$');
var m = re.exec(html);
if (m != null)
alert('match');
else
alert('nomatch');
```

The purpose of the regexp is to check whether a string contains any dates. However it never finds any dates. I have tested the regexp with an online regexp tool.

Comment: Just as a suggestion: Better match only for something that looks dateish (e.g. `##.##.####`) and then check if the match is actually a valid date (month between 1 and 12 etc.). That makes things much simpler and you can actually check e.g. if the given month e.g. has a 31st or not.

Comment: Here's a site that might help: http://www.mkyong.com/regular-expressions/how-to-validate-date-with-regular-expression/

Comment: There's no need for you to use the constructor in creating your pattern. These are used normally only if your pattern needs to reference variables. The literal `/pattern/` [is better for performance](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions).

Comment: replacing single quote ' with slash / will have better results. you might also want to start with the regexp from the top.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to find `whether a string contains any dates`, then having `^` at the start and `$` isn't going to help - as they denote to match the very start and end *of the string*.

To find the date within a string that contains other text (or even whitespace), use this...

```
var re = new RegExp('(19|20)\d\d[- /.](0[1-9]|1[012])[- /.](0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])');
```

**UPDATE**

Anton has already figured out a solution - however, while the above solution is better than the original, it's still not correct, as the `\d` needs to be escaped (to `\\d`) in order for it to work when contained within quotes.  So instead it should be...

```
var re = new RegExp('(19|20)\\d\\d[- /.](0[1-9]|1[012])[- /.](0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])');
```

However, in hindsight I agree with all others that as it's not a dynamic pattern, the best solution is to use the `/pattern/` syntax

Answer (score 0):

I did as @Utkanos said and used the /pattern/-syntax instead like this

```
if (/(19|20)\d\d[- /.](0[1-9]|1[012])[- /.](0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])/.test(html))
```

Then it worked :)

Comment: Hate to say it, but the part that actually "worked" was removing the `^` and `$`, not the use of the `/pattern/` syntax... but glad you've got it sorted

Comment: Thing is i tried to remove ^ and $ but it made no difference. Then i tried /pattern/ instead and then it worked

Comment: Oh, OK - then I apologise.  Just as a matter of interest, *were* you trying to match the entire string as a date, or find the date within a longer string? (Also, I've just realised that having your original pattern with `'` characters would have resulted in the `\d` to be treated as an escape character... you would have needed `\\d` instead... that's another reason why the `/pattern/` syntax worked

Comment: It was the date only in the string.